# How to make this code Php 5.2 backwards-compatible - reference the class using a variable

Tags: php, oop

Does anyone know how to convert this code to be PHP 5.2 compatible?

```
$myClass = 'ValidClassName';
$instance = $myClass::factory(array('arg' => 'value));
```

I know in PHP 5.3

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

And without realizing it, I was using it. Then on a Php 5.2 enviroment, I get the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

So I am trying to figure out how to convert that code into something that will be at least 5.2 backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of `call_user_func()`:

As of 5.2.3:

```
$instance = call_user_func($myClass.'::factory', array('arg' => 'value'));
```

And I think this works on 5.2.0:

```
$instance = call_user_func(array($myClass, 'factory'), array('arg' => 'value'));
```

Comment: This is the one that worked in the context of what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 6):

Just reference the class function with an arrow:

```
$className = 'ValidClassName';

$myClass = new $className();

$instance = $myClass -> factory(array('arg' => 'value));
```

Comment: This approach also has the added benefit of actually being OOP, instead of procedural programming paradigm, that is used with static class methods.